# Visual Studio 2019 is Broken! UWP applications won't link to .NET Standard 2.1 libraries

Tags: uwp, .net-standard

I was forced into upgrading to Visual Studio 16.3.0 today because some Nuget packages were released that wouldn't work with .NET Core 2.2.  To my horror, my client UWP application which makes extensive use of shared .NET Standard libraries was gushing errors.  So then I took a virgin UWP application and tried to link it to a virgin .NET Standard library.  Same failure.

```
NU1201: Project ClassLibrary1 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586). Project ClassLibrary1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
NU1201: Project ClassLibrary1 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-arm. Project ClassLibrary1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
NU1201: Project ClassLibrary1 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-arm-aot. Project ClassLibrary1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
NU1201: Project ClassLibrary1 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-arm64-aot. Project ClassLibrary1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
NU1201: Project ClassLibrary1 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x64. Project ClassLibrary1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
NU1201: Project ClassLibrary1 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x64-aot. Project ClassLibrary1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
NU1201: Project ClassLibrary1 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x86. Project ClassLibrary1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
NU1201: Project ClassLibrary1 is not compatible with uap10.0.10586 (UAP,Version=v10.0.10586) / win10-x86-aot. Project ClassLibrary1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
NuGet package restore failed. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.
```

Is anyone else seeing this?  Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: So... what do you want?

Comment: What framework version are you specifying?

Comment: Like I said, virgin.  Out of the box you get .NET Standard 2.0 if you don't change anything.  I didn't change any settings when I created the UWP application and linked it to a .NET Standard library.

Comment: UWP does not move that fast.  Next major Win10 update, perhaps, you'd still want to wait until you're sure that most users have in fact updated.  That takes a while, version 1709 (Fall Creators) is a safe bet right now.  If the Dependencies info is accurate then just use an older release of the package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using .NET Standard 2.1 with UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58070082/using-net-standard-2-1-with-uwp)

Answer (score 3):

**According to the error message you got:**

Your uwp project targets `10.0.10586`, but it's not compatible with `.net standard 2.0`.

Please see [.NET implementation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support). To reference `.net standard 2.0` library, your uwp project should target at least `10.0.16299`. See:

[image]

Also, you may get help from this [similar issue](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/462#issuecomment-365141931).

So you can change your minimum version to at least 16299 to resolve this issue. Or you can choose to reference `.net standard 1.4` project instead of 2.0 version.

And to your title, see the pic above and you can find UWP does not support .net standard right now.