Unable to install Google.FlatBuffers Nuget package for the UWP application
I got the below error while installing FlatBuffers package for the UWP app
NU1202: Package Google.FlatBuffers 24.3.25 is not compatible with uap10.0.17763 (UAP,Version=v10.0.17763) / win10-x86. Package Google.FlatBuffers 24.3.25 supports:

net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)


Sorry, currently UWP only supports .NET Standard 2.0. .NET Standard 2.1,.net6 and .net8 are not supported in UWP.
Related discussions can be found here.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Add-NET-678-support-to-UWP/1596483
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077778/17316773
